# rails rspec error generating controller

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec

Soo the problem occured after i got rspec installed when i do `rails g controller name` i get the following error:

> /.rbenv/versions/2.2.3/lib/ruby/2.2.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:54:in
>   `require': cannot load such file -- bundler/setup (LoadError)     from
>   /home/ev0lution/.rbenv/versions/2.2.3/lib/ruby/2.2.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:54:in`
>   require'     from /home/ev0lution/RailsP/ticketee/config/boot.rb:3:in
>   `<top (required)>'    from bin/rails:7:in`require_relative'  from
>   bin/rails:7:in `'

i havent even done anything with it yet only created 1 single test file and i need a controller for it.

Comment: Did you install rspec using bundler? If so, try `bundle exec rails g controller name`.

Comment: @SvenKoschnicke okeii so i did like you said and i got a lot of missing gems i already installed 10 manually soo idk how long this will go on maybe you have a idea why is it so?

Comment: @SvenKoschnicke btw i did rails s got the same error

Comment: Bundler maintains a separate set of gems specifically for your project, so it needs to reinstall gems, even if they are already available as gems on your machine (installed with `gem install`). But the big benefit is that you don't have problems with conflicting gem requirements of multiple projects.

Comment: @SvenKoschnicke well i figured i'll create a new project and try again maybe i missed something so as i created a new project i got this error `/.rbenv/versions/2.2.3/lib/ruby/2.2.0/rubygems.rb:243:in `bin_path': cant find gem bundler (>= 0) (Gem::GemNotFoundException)` think the whole problem is within that maybe i installed rails incorrelctly

Comment: The bundler gem should be installed along with the rails gem (it is a dependency). The bundler docs show how to use bundler in rails: http://bundler.io/rails3.html . So its `gem install rails`, `rails new myapp`, `cd myapp`, `bundle install`, `rails g controller somecontroller`.

Answer (score 1):

Try run `bundle install` in your application. seems like some gem is missing. And if command still give similar error try run command with `bundle exec`.